# set mouse=a not working on Vim / Neovim in iTerm2

Tags: vim, neovim, iterm2

I am using iTerm2, running Neovim v0.9.1, but have same issue with Vim v9.0.
I have `set mouse=a` enabled on Neovim and mouse functionality is not working. I am unable to resize windows, select tabs, position the cursor, and scroll. I've searched SO as well as iTerm's documentation and have yet been able to pin down the source of the problem.

Running `:checkhealth` yields the following for `Clipboard`

```
Clipboard (optional)
   - OK Clipboard tool found: pbcopy
```

Here is a screen shot of `Session` -> `Terminal State`:

[image: Session->Terminal State]

I also have the same settings on my work computer, and the mouse works fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please, do not offer vim key-binding solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: @romainl perhaps this question didn't meet your criteria for a Stack Overflow question, but your response is over the top. I will rephrase to be more specific, but, considering the tags, `iterm`, `vim` and `neovim` and a title that contains `set mouse=a`, which is a common solution to full mouse functionality, I still believe the question is clear.
In addition, I added results from `:checkhealth` and a screen shot of user input modes from iTerm2, showing that I attempted to place some troubleshooting info into the question.

Comment: I disagree. SO provides tags, `iterm2`, `neovim` and `vim`. Therefore, this is certainly an appropriate forum. Would you thus remove all of [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iterm2+vim) as well?

Comment: Many of them, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Enable mouse reporting.

[image]

- https://copyprogramming.com/howto/vim-not-working-under-iterm2